# Can I remove only the inventory that pops up by pressing "~"?

Tags: roblox

I use this code

```
game.StarterGui:SetCoreGuiEnabled(Enum.CoreGuiType.Backpack, false)
```

But when I play, the bottom bar was removed too

I want to remove only inventory that pops up when press "~"

I also tried to access the core GUI, but it was blocked

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but I do not think that is possible yet, since there are only 7 different types of CoreGuiTypes (https://create.roblox.com/docs/reference/engine/enums/CoreGuiType) and, correct me if I'm wrong, you can't access the core gui where the backpack is located.